# Send username to AWS Lambda function triggered when user is registered through AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

I am trying to write a Lambda function that makes a folder in an s3 bucket when a newly confirmed Cognito user. This will allow me to keep that user's access limited to their folder. I have created a Lambda function that can list the current users registered in the user pool. I know Cognito has a "confirmation event" and "post authentication" event trigger, and I have selected my function to run on that trigger.

But I do not know how to make the folder when the user authenticates or confirmed from that event. Screenshot below is of my Lambda code.

Here is my code for post authentication trigger, but it does not work:

```
from __future__ import print_function
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Send post authentication data to Cloudwatch logs
    print ("Authentication successful")
    print ("Trigger function =", event['triggerSource'])
    print ("User pool = us-east-1_EVPcl4p64", event['userPoolId'])
    print ("App client ID = ", event['callerContext']['clientId'])
    print ("User ID = ", event['userName'])

    # Return to Amazon Cognito
    return event
```

Here is the code for list user. It works, but now how to fetch only user name and on that basis create a folder in an s3 bucket?

```
import json
import boto3
import re
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

    response = client.list_users(
    UserPoolId='us-east-1_EVPcl4p64',
    AttributesToGet=['email']
    )
    x =  response    

    print json.dumps(x)


    print(y["email"]) 
    pattern = '^@gmail.com$'
    test_string = response
    result = re.match(pattern, test_string)

    print(response)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `PostConfirmation` trigger instead. Post authentication trigger will fire every time when a user signs in.

Here is how you get the email address:

```
email = event['request']['userAttributes']['email']
```

Here is how you create an S3 "folder" for that user using email as the folder name:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = 'example-bucket-name'
directory_path = f"users/{email}/"
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=directory_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my query can you please elaborate or clarify it bit more since I am a newbie in this task and got stuck for 3 days.

Comment: my code is -- `import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = client.list_users(
    UserPoolId='us-east-1_EVPcl4p64',
    AttributesToGet=['email']
    email = event['request']['userAttributes']['email']
    bucket_name = 'myprac'
    directory_path = f"users/{email}/"
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=directory_path)
    )
    print(response)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
 }`

Comment: {
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 11)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 11\n        bucket = s3.bucket(\"documenthandle\")\n"
  ]
}

Comment: START RequestId: 453ede06-529a-4f3c-89aa-e127af97e165 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 11)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 11
        bucket = s3.bucket("documenthandle")END RequestId: 453ede06-529a-4f3c-89aa-e127af97e165
REPORT RequestId: 453ede06-529a-4f3c-89aa-e127af97e165 Duration: 1.75 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 50 MB Init Duration: 128.27 ms

Comment: Looks like it should be `s3.Bucket("documenthandle")`?

Comment: No, it doesn't work I had changed ....but can you please tell me that the code is right ?? since I am trying to continue from the past 3 days.